# Can we add dilated layers to Graph Neural Nets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, graph-neural-network

GNNs are not as deep as CNNs (due to over-smoothing and other factors). Is this possible to have dilated in gcn?

Comment: I thought CNNs could be thought of as GNNs.

Answer (score 1):

I googled and found this paper: [DeepGCNs: Can GCNs Go as Deep as CNNs?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.03751.pdf).

[image]

but they found that it only works with residual connections:

> Without such connections, performance
> can actually degrade with dilated graph convolutions. The
> reason for this is probably that these varying neighbors result in ‘worse’ gradients, which further hinder convergence
> when residual graph connections are not used.

Comment: It sounds like the answer is "maybe, but with caveats".